# With multiple Python installs, how does MacPorts know which one to install MySQLdb for?

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I just upgraded the default Python 2.5 on Leopard to 2.6 via the installer on www.python.org. Upon doing so, the MySQLdb I had installed was no longer found. So I tried reinstalling it via `port install py-mysql`, and it succeeded, but MySQLdb was still not `import`able. So then I tried to `python install python26` with `python_select python26` and it succeeded, but it doesn't appear that it is getting precedence over the python.org install:

`$ which python

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python`

When I would expect it to be something like `/opt/local/bin/python`

My `path` environment is: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/bsr/bin`

Anyway, when I try `port install py-mysql` but how does it know where to install the Python MySQL library?

Comment: I got one question answered: the first binary found on that path is the one that is used as the default. I figured it would be the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MacPorts` python ports generally follow a pattern: if the port name starts with just `py-`, it is configured to install into MacPorts python2.4.  Likewise `py25-` requires python2.5.  For the MacPorts python2.6, you want [this port](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=py26-mysql):

```
sudo port install py26-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need python_select (or is it select_python?) to change the default python used.