# How to make python_select work for '$>python' command?

Tags: python, macos, mysql

I installed a couple of pythons in different versions with macports, and the apple python 2.6 is also working. Now I need to run a program which requires MySQLdb package support in python, and this package was installed to the python I installed by macports. The program tells me that there is no MySQLdb installed, so I guess it is the apple python working for that program.

I searched for some help and found python_select for switching between pythons. However after the command

```
$>sudo python_select python25
```

told me that it selected the version "python25" for python, when I type

```
$>python
```

it is still apple python 2.6 that launches.

The question is that how can I make python25(the one with MySQLdb) work for the program rather than apple python?

Another important thing, the program is NOT a .py file and needs to be compiled before running. So do I need to re-install this program? My Mac OS version is Snow Leopard 10.6.

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: For additional information, I just found this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499572/with-multiple-python-installs-how-does-macports-know-which-one-to-install-mysqld
I have the same problem as this question. Hope this will help for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, MacPorts installs user programs (or links to them) in `/opt/local/bin`.  The MacPorts `select_python` command selects which python instance is linked to `/opt/local/bin/python`.  It has no effect (nor should it) on what Apple installs in `/usr/bin`, which is where the Apple-supplied `python` and `python2.x` commands are.

To invoke the MacPorts python2.5, you either need to ensure that `/opt/local/bin` precedes `/usr/bin` on your shell `$PATH` (you can do this by modifying your `.bash_profile` or other shell initialization script) or you can simply invoke the desired python with an absolute path reference:

```
$ /usr/bin/python your-program.py
```

to use the Apple-supplied default python;

```
$ /opt/local/bin/python your-program.py
```

to use the version selected with `python_select`, or:

```
$ /opt/local/bin/python2.5 your-program.py
```

to explicitly select the MacPorts 2.5 one.

EDIT:

To modify your search PATH to use MacPorts, add this line to `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: I heard that 'export' only lasts for the terminal session, is it true?

Comment: Generally, each terminal session starts a new "login" shell which means the commands in your ~/.bash_profile will be executed for each terminal session.  The export command tells the shell to pass along the value of that environment variable ($PATH) to any subsequent subprocesses that it creates.  So the net effect is that exported variables will be available in all terminal sessions and the programs running in them - unless you explicitly unset them or change their value.

Comment: For posterity: python_select command doesn't seem to exist for me. To select the python you want macports to use one must do `sudo port select python --list` and then `sudo port select python python27` (for 2.7 for example). Also, as Ned said, make sure that /opt/local/bin comes before /usr/bin in your $PATH. This last part ensures that `python` command uses the MacPorts version of python and not Apple's.

Comment: @Nick: it appears that was a fairly recent change in MacPorts.  https://trac.macports.org/changeset/78591

Comment: Thanks for the detail. I did a 'port cat python_select' and saw "This port installs files that allow 'port select' to...". That's how it all started. =)

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure with Mac, coz I never use it before.

but in Linux, when I do `whereis python`

It will show like `/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python` ....etc

in my `.bashrc` file, I just `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH` when I want `/usr/local/bin` more priority

or you still can run like

```
/usr/bin/python yourpython.py
```

or

```
/usr/local/bin/python yourpython.py
```

depends on your python install locations

just my 2 cents. sorry if my answer dont make you any helps.

Comment: Never mind. In mac when I do 'which python' it returns what path 'python' is referring to. If you can tell me how to modify the reference I'll be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

'python' in the Mac is just a link. Do a 'which python', 'cd' to the directory in which 'python' resides, and then do an 'ls -a py*'. You shall see where python is pointing too. If you want that python to point to your different version of python, just make it link to the right version.