# Mac OS X pygame input goes to Terminal instead of Python

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pygame

I'm having trouble running a pygame based app on Mac OS X via Terminal.  Input events such as keystrokes go to the Terminal instead of my Python app, and are detected by pygame.

For example, I have the following test script:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

done = False
while not done:
    pygame.event.pump()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        done = True
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        print "got here"
```

Neither K_ESCAPE nor K_SPACE will be handled by this script when I run it from a Mac OS X Terminal, but Terminal will echo back the spaces.

I'm running the MacPorts port of pygame (py-game), which depends on Python 2.4, and I've also used python_select to make python24 the active version.

Comment: Does that pop up a pygame window? Did you try focusing that window?

Comment: Yes it pops up a window, and yes I tried giving that window focus.  It seems to accept the focus but the input still appears in Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default py-game on Mac Ports has the problem you describe. A work-around is to install the  py-game2.6 target instead. This works for me with OS X 10.6.7.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the pygame.K_* constants actually correspond to the correct values for your keyboard? For the record I tried your code in Linux on a MacBook Pro and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: I've tried this code in Linux as well and it works fine.  I'm pretty sure the problem is with my Terminal environment and/or Pygame config, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: One more suggestion (in case you haven't solved this), are you sure `python_select` is working the way you want it to?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768881/how-to-make-python-select-work-for-python-command