# Pygame doesn't catch keydown events on mac

Tags: python, macos, pygame, keydown

When I am trying to catch keys pressed, they are printed in Terminal, but not caught by pygame and the script. Script is executed as follows:

```
>>>import scriptname
>>>scriptname.wa()
```

scriptname file:
import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *

```
def wa():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), 0, 32)

    alive_key = True

    while alive_key:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                alive_key = False
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_q:
                print '\nThis is not happening\n'

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            pygame.event.post(
              pygame.event.Event(KEYDOWN, key=K_q, mod=0, unicode=u'q'))

        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
```

If events are created on mouse press (as presented in code), they work.

I am using OS X 10.8.5, python 2.7, pygame2.7 1.9.1. Everything works perfectly in Windows 7 with similar configuration.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if this issue is similar to [this other issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718897/mac-os-x-pygame-input-goes-to-terminal-instead-of-python)...

Comment: Thanks for the link but python2.6 didn't help, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
elif event.type == KEYDOWN or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    # for testing purpose
    print event 

    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
        print '\nThis is not happening\n
```

I'm using OS X 10.9.5, python 2.7.7, pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7. Had the similar problem as yours earlier. I found this solution here: http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Python:Pygame_keyboard_input

I think this is not mac's fault, possibly.

Comment: Can't test this, don't have this Mac anymore. This does not look like a solution at all. I tried that before and no key events were caught by python.