# Pygame mac key error

Tags: macos, pygame

I'm on a mac and I'm using pygame. My code works fine except nothing happens when I the keys are pressed. Terminal prints [B^[[C^[[B^[[D^[[D something like this. Could you help me?﻿

Comment: Please post [your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're running it in terminal. Running it through a python IDE such as IDLE will work, or you could try the answers listed in [this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718897/mac-os-x-pygame-input-goes-to-terminal-instead-of-python)